# how to show/hide dynamically create division using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using below code for my project. i want to toggle (show/hide) div using button. that divisions and its button generate by using ngFor.

```
    <div *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
     <span *ngFor="let key of room | keys">
      {{key}} : {{room[key]}} <button id="toggleDiv"> Show/Hide</button>
      </span>
  </div>>
```

Comment: do you want to show/hide the `div` that has the `button` inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a visible property to room and toggle on click

```
<div *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
     <span *ngFor="let key of room | keys">
      <ng-container *ngIf="room.visible">{{key}} : {{room[key]}}</ng-container> <button id="toggleDiv" (click)="room.visible = !room.visible"> Show/Hide</button>
      </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is dynamic one. according to this solution, ID repeat in all element.